# installing and using conda within a sudo-called bash script

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have a bash script which installs some software with `apt-get` as well as download and installs `miniconda3`. Later I would like to utilize `conda` command without restarting the shell. This script is called with `sudo` but for all the things related to `conda` I want to pose as a regular user, see below:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# we are operating in the user's home dir
sudo -u $SUDO_USER bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p miniconda3
source [path_to_the_user_home]/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
sudo -u $SUDO_USER -H -s eval $(conda shell.bash hook)
sudo -u $SUDO_USER conda --version
```

However, I get an error that the command `conda` is not recognized. Interestingly, if the last line would be just `conda --version` then it is correctly recognised. It seems that the 2nd to last line worked for root, but not the user (which is exactly what I want)

Comment: Have you tried exporting `PATH=[path_to_the_user_home]/miniconda3/condabin:$PATH` or adding it to ~/.bashrc and sourcing it?

Comment: @jared_mamrot: I just did, I tried both suggestions and the result is the same - it works with `conda --version` but when I try to run as the user it says: 'sudo: conda: command not found'

Comment: Right - one step forward - try changing `sudo -u $SUDO_USER -H -s eval $(conda shell.bash hook)` to `sudo -u $SUDO_USER -H -s eval $([path_to_the_user_home]/miniconda3/condabin/conda shell.bash hook)` and include the lines `sudo -u $SUDO_USER source [path_to_the_user_home]/miniconda3/bin/activate` and `sudo -u $SUDO_USER [path_to_the_user_home]/miniconda3/condabin/conda init` before `sudo -u $SUDO_USER conda --version`

Comment: @jared_mamrot: I have modified the code and I got `sudo: source: command not found`

Comment: @jared_mamrot: I have also tried to activate without `sudo -u $SUDO_USER`. Now I got a message back that the .bashrc have been updated but I need to close and re-open the shell for the changes to take effect. Still conda is unrecognised. I have also added source .bashrc just above the conda calls. This however did not change anything...

Comment: I'm stumped, sorry. I'll boot up a VM to replicate the problem and continue troubleshooting when I have some spare time (maybe next week). Sorry I can't be more help with this. Perhaps try reaching out to the devs? e.g. https://github.com/orgs/conda/people

Comment: You probably need to use `sudo -i -u ...` as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35338/su-vs-sudo-s-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bash).

Comment: @not2qubit: I have just added `-i` to all these commands, no effect...

Comment: Also try `-s`. Also, it's very hard to see what you're doing without a command log. Can you post a log on *pastebin* or something?  It seem to me, that if conda is in the path, it should run! So I suspect there are other environment variables that have been neglected. Maybe provide relevant parts of: `env |sort |grep -v "^[ORIGINAL_]*PATH="`?

Comment: @not2qubit
I am working on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04, VM via VirtualBox. I have created a minimal example shell script that would recreate the error: https://pastebin.com/iJNLy3u2
The installation is clean, I do not expect environmental variables but I can post whatever you need - what are the relevant parts?
Also `-s` and `-i` are exclusive options, I have tried both ways with no success...